# Removed a container using command docker rm -f container_name, then when execute docker inspect container_name it returns a json output is it a bug

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu, deployment, docker-container

I removed a container using the following command

```
docker rm -f container_name
```

then when I execute

```
docker inspect container_name
```

i get the json output is it a bug ?

When a docker container is removed, and after that a docker inspect is done it should return nothing.

Comment: There may be a volume with the same name (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/). Try to specificy the type of the object you want to inspect (that is, a container): docker inspect --type=container container_name